# doxygen show unresolvable references

Tags: reference, doxygen

is there a way to display references to unresolvable functions or globals in Doxygen output? It seems to just hide everything it can't find whilst parsing. If I could get these separately that would be a bonus - even just as warning output to the logfile.

So far I have tried:

```
REFERENCES_RELATION  = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS = NO      (i believe this is just for callgraph output?)   
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS   = NO
# WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED = YES   (this only shows warnings for resolvable members with no docs)
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES = YES
```

I was hoping to use it to track down unresolvable references in some old code i want to import but so far it hasn't been much help ):